# connection error while connecting mongodb to node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, database-connection

after I started server at port 27017, opened another window and run my server program it is showing the connection error as follow

```
C:\node-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:242
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                              ^
AssertionError: { [MongoError: connect UNKNOWN 127.0.0.1:27017 - 
Local(undefined:undefined)]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'connect UNKNOWN  == null
at C:\node-mongodb\simple-server.js:8:12
at C:\node-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:330:20
at C:\node-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:231:14
at null.<anonymous> (C:\node-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:240:9)
at g (events.js:260:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at null.<anonymous(C:\nodemongodb\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongo
db-core\lib\topologies\server.js:218:12)
at g (events.js:260:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
```

I tried removing lock file repairing mongodb and other solutions that are given for other similar questions but they are not working.
please tell my why this error is coming and how I can resolve it.
I am running on windows xp(32-bit).
This is the simple-server.js file:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
assert.equal(err,null);
console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    var collection = db.collection("dishes");
    collection.insertOne({name: "nerd21", description: "test"},
  function(err,result){
    assert.equal(err,null);
    console.log("After Insert:");
    console.log(result.ops);
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){
       assert.equal(err,null);
       console.log("Found:");
       console.log(docs);
       db.dropCollection("dishes", function(err, result){
           assert.equal(err,null);
           db.close();
           });
    });
});
```

});

screenshot of command prompt is as follows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGIiF.png)

Comment: can you connect to mongo through the shell? Can you post the code you use to connect to mongo in your application?

Comment: can you show your simple-server.js and try type mongo command in cmd windows

Comment: robert: I can connect to mongo using shell.